# How to send data from Json using Ajax in jquery for html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to show data from 5 rows of Database (MySQL) to rows of table using on success of `jQuery AJAX` call. The data is in `JSON` format.

**Issue:** I am not able to figure out to get all of those rows. I can get only one row but `console` showed me all the rows in `JSON` format.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '<?php echo base_url('ads/select_post'); ?>',
   data: {},
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   success: function (data) {
     $.each(data, function (i, val) { 
       console.log(val.name);
       $("#name").html(val.name);
       $("#price").html(val.price);
       $("#addr").html(val.addr);
       $("#des").html(val.des);
       $("#viewed").html(val.viewed);
       $("#status").html(val.status);
    });
 }
});
```

**Console output:**

```
[{"name":"dfasdfas","price":"0","addr":"dfasdfas","des":"sadfdfasdfasdf","viewed":"0","img":"","status"
:"1"},{"name":"Heng","price":"0","addr":" dflkas;df","des":"asdfasdf"
,"viewed":"0","img":"","status":"1"},{"name":"asdDasdA","price":"0","addr":"asdADasd","des":"ASDasdASD"
,"viewed":"0","img":"","status":"1"},{"name":"asdfas","price":"0","addr":"fasdfas","des":"dfasdf","viewed"
:"0","img":"","status":"1"},{"name":"asdf","price":"0","addr":"asdfasdfas","des":"asdfasdfasdf","viewed"
:"0","img":"","status":"1"}]
```

`HTML` of the table i am sending data to,

```
<tbody id="items">
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><a><div id="name"></div> </a></td> 
  <td><a><div id="price"></div> </a></td> 
  <td><a><div id"addr"></div></a></td> 
  <td><div id="des"></div> </td> 
  <td><a><div id="viewed"></div></a></td> 
  <td><a><div id="status"></div></a></td> 
 </tr>
```

Please advise.

Comment: I think you have to create table rows dynamically

Comment: Because you use id selector (id="name", id="price"...) and your code does append any new table row, so that no new row in the table will be created. Don't use id selector in your template, you need to travel through your data and append a new row.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Lots of good answers, but since I've created an example I'll post that too. If nothing else it might give you, or someone else, an alternative solution. I'm using classes instead of Id's, and keep your original structure.*

Since this was accepted as answer I should also mention why your code failed:
 Your `each` loop is continually overwriting the contents of your table row data, instead of creating new rows. Another thing that needed fixing is that  you had given the columns Id's, and those cannot stay (as they were) if you want to repeat the rows, since Id's within a page must be unique.

There are many methods to create new elements. I chose `clone()` as I figure you would always have a row for header that could easily be used to clone/copy. Also I added a *unique Id* attribute to each `tr`. These are not really used in the current implementation below, but it might be good to have as reference later in your project.

```js
var data = [{"name":"dfasdfas","price":"0","addr":"dfasdfas","des":"sadfdfasdfasdf","viewed":"0","img":"","status"
:"1"},{"name":"Heng","price":"0","addr":" dflkas;df","des":"asdfasfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdfas"
,"viewed":"0","img":"","status":"1"},{"name":"asdDasdA","price":"0","addr":"asdADasd","des":"ASDasdASD"
,"viewed":"0","img":"","status":"1"},{"name":"asdfas","price":"0","addr":"fasdfas","des":"dfasdf","viewed"
:"0","img":"","status":"1"},{"name":"asdf","price":"0","addr":"asdfasdfas","des":"asdfasdfasdf","viewed"
:"0","img":"","status":"1"}];

//place within the Ajax success
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
  var currRow = $("#tr0").clone().appendTo($('#items')).attr('id','tr' + (i + 1));
  currRow.find('td:eq(0)').html(i + 1);
  currRow.find('.name').html(val.name);
  currRow.find('.price').html(val.price);
  currRow.find('.addr').html(val.addr);
  currRow.find('.des').html(val.des);
  currRow.find('.viewed').html(val.viewed);
  currRow.find('.status').html(val.status);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="items">
    <tr id="tr0">
      <td>Id</td>
      <td><a><div class="name">Name</div></a></td>
      <td><a><div class="price">Price</div></a></td>
      <td><a><div class="addr">Addr</div></a></td>
      <td><div class="des">Des</div></td>
      <td><a><div class="viewed">Viewed</div></a></td>
      <td><a><div class="status">Status</div></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Mackan That is a good one. If Cambodiachannel  wants the data from the json only needs to be in the table, he can remove all the rows before appending the first clone

Answer (score 5):

You can try this, I test it locally and it works:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url('ads/select_post'); ?>',
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            var tr = "<tr>" +
                "<td>"+ (i + 1) + "</td>" +
                "<td>"+ val.name + "</td>" +
                "<td>"+ val.price + "</td>" +
                "<td>"+ val.addr + "</td>" +
                "<td>"+ val.des + "</td>" +
                "<td>"+ val.viewed + "</td>" +
                "<td>"+ val.status + "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
            $(tr).appendTo("tbody");
        });
    }
});
```

And your html `table`:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="items">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You used tr to appenTo but if I have two or three table How should I used ID instead of this

Answer (score 5):

You need something like this:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/m1vkrg1m/2/)**

**HTML Structure**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Sl No.</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Viewed</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="items">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
    $.each(data, function (i, val) { 
           $("tbody#items").append("<tr><td>"+(i+1)+"</td><td><a><div>"+val.addr+"</div></a></td>"
                +"<td><a><div>"+val.des+"</div></a></td>"
                +"<td><a><div>"+val.img+"</div></a></td>"
                +"<td><a><div>"+val.name+"</div></a></td>"
                +"<td><a><div>"+val.price+"</div></a></td>"
                +"<td><a><div>"+val.status+"</div></a></td>"
                +"<td><a><div>"+val.viewed+"</div></a></td></tr>");
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to create table rows() in the ajax success.
And you should not use same ids in the td tags.

```
var html = "";
$.ajax({
  url: '<?php echo base_url('ads/select_post'); ?>',
   data: {},
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   success: function (data) {
     $.each(data, function (i, val) { 
        console.log(val.name);

        html +="<tr>";
        html += "<td>" + val.name + "</td>" ;
        html += "<td>" + val.price + "</td>" ;
        html += "<td>" + val.addr + "</td>" ;
        html += "<td>" + val.des + "</td>" ;
        html += "<td>" + val.viewed + "</td>" ;
        html += "<td>" + val.status + "</td>" ;
        html +="</tr>";
    });
    $("$items").html(html);
  }
});
```

Your html:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="items">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use appendTo() like this.

$(html).appendTo("#items");

Answer (score 3):

You probably need some code like this, This is rough idea you can let me know if you don't get it

```
this.tableElement = jQuery('<table/>', {
}).appendTo(gridWrapElement);

var tableBody = jQuery('<tbody/>', {
    'class': 'eg-table-body'
});

this.tableBodyRow = jQuery('<tr/>', {
});

var scope = this;
var columns = [{
        name:"Name",
        dataIndex:"name",
        width: "33%"
    },{
        name:"Price",
        dataIndex:"price",
        width: "33%"
    },{
        name:"Address",
        dataIndex:"addr",
        width: "34%"
    }];
$.each(this.columns, function(index, column) {
    var tableBody = jQuery('<td/>', {
        width: column.width,
        columnDataIndex: column.dataIndex,
        columnIndex: index
    });

    jQuery('<div/>', {
        html: "<a>" + column.name + "</a>",
        class: "eg-table-Body-div"
    }).appendTo(tableBody);

    tableBody.appendTo(scope.tableBodyRow);
    scope.tableBodyItems.push(tableBody);
});

jQuery(this.tableBodyRow).appendTo(tableBody);
jQuery(tableBody).appendTo(this.tableElement);
```

Comment: I don't know how to send to html

Answer (score 3):

```
var body = '';
$.each(val,function(i,j){
  body = body + '<tr><td>'+i+1+'</td>';
  body = body + '<td>'+j.name+'</td>';
  body = body + '<td>'+j.price+'</td>';
  body = body + '<td>'+j.addr+'</td>';
  body = body + '<td>'+j.des+'</td>';
  body = body + '<td>'+j.viewed+'</td>';
  body = body + '<td>'+j.status+'</td></tr>';
});
$('#items').html(body);
```

This will give you the table with values

Answer (score 3):

It is better if you can rows dynamically. Then append generated html into tbody table like example below :

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tbody id="items">
    <tr>
        <td>No.</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>price</td>
        <td>addr</td>
        <td>des</td>
        <td>viewed</td>
        <td>status</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**JS**

```
var data = [{
"name": "dfasdfas",
    "price": "0",
    "addr": "dfasdfas",
    "des": "sadfdfasdfasdf",
    "viewed": "0",
    "img": "",
    "status": "1"
}, {
"name": "asdDasdA",
    "price": "0",
    "addr": "asdADasd",
    "des": "ASDasdASD",
    "viewed": "0",
    "img": "",
    "status": "1"
}];

/************ put this inside ajax success block*/
var output;
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
output += '<tr><td>' + i + '</td>' +
    '<td><a><div id="name">' + val.name + '</div> </a></td>' +
    '<td><a><div id="price">' + val.price + '</div> </a></td>' +
    '<td><a><div id"addr">'+ val.addr +'</div></a></td>' +
    '<td><div id="des">' + val.des + '</div> </td>' +
    '<td><a><div id="viewed">' + val.viewed + '</div></a></td>' +
    '<td><a><div id="status">'+
val.status+'</div></a></td></tr>';
});

$('#items').append(output);
/************ end */
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/zktvrwgu/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = '<tr>';
 for(var i = 0 ;i < data.length;i++){ 
  var val = data[i];
  html += '<td>'+i+'</td>'+
            '<td><a><div id="name'+id+'">'+ val.name +'</div> </a></td>'+ 
            '<td><a><div id="price'+id+'">'+ val.price +'</div> </a></td>'+ 
            '<td><a><div id"addr'+id+'">+ val.addr +</div></a></td>'+ 
            '<td><div id="des'+id+'">' +val.des+ '</div> </td>'+ 
            '<td><a><div id="viewed'+id+'">'+ val.viewed +'</div></a></td>'+ 
            '<td><a><div id="status'+id+'">' val.status '</div></a></td>';
}

 $("#items").html(html);
```

Comment: There should not be id of the div in for loop, as it will not make sense at all, cause you can assign single id to single item only.

Comment: @ParagBhayani I am assigning single id to single item.

Comment: If there are 15 items in data array then it will create 15 divs with '<div id="name">' and, so 15 divs with single id is not what it should be... I hope you got this...

Comment: @ParagBhayani yes 15 items in data array will create 15 different rows and each rows has id associated with it.

Comment: @ParagBhayani please refer my second line in for loop.

Comment: Yep, better would be to increment the id inside the loop to keep it unique if it really required.

Comment: @Rohit416 why to use to use another variable when i have variable i in for   loop and use it as unique index.

Comment: Who told you to do so? using `i` should be ideal.

Comment: You are not getting me, what will you get if you run document.getElementById('name') ? or $('#name')?

Comment: @ParagBhayani you can use name+i as id

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `Its shows all data in table.`
 http://jsfiddle.net/Navneethk/zcpp51tc/2/

Comment: This can go in comments. There is plenty of land available there.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You were assigning all 5 data row to the same template so that you only see the last data set returned. 
You should create those 5 row dynamically by using createElement or jQuery.